# How can I include the result of a method call when exporting to JSON using Go?

Tags: json, go

Imagine the following:

```
type Ninja struct {
  name string
}

func (n *Ninja) Shurikens() int {
  return 2
}

n := &Ninja{"Super Ninja"}
```

I'd like to serialize this to JSON, and obtain the following:

```
{'Name': 'Super Ninja', 'Shurikens':2}
```

It's just a simplification of what I need ( calling methods on structs, and including that output in the resulting JSON ).

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: json.MarshalIndent from the std lib so far, right now I'm also trying to generate that JSON using text/template, but does not feel like the best solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer, you can't, your `Shurikens` has to be a field.

Long answer, well, you can use a custom `MarshalJSON` like [this](http://play.golang.org/p/5yDNT7YpJu):

```
func (n *Ninja) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {

    return []byte(fmt.Sprintf(`{"Name":"%s", "Shurikens":%d}`, n.name, n.Shurikens())), nil
}

func main() {
    n := []*Ninja{{"X"}, {"Y"}}
    b, err := json.Marshal(n)
    fmt.Println(string(b), err)
}
```

Keep in mind that your `name` field isn't exported since it doesn't start with a capital letter, so you will not be able to Unmarshal your struct.